# Show tasks which have taking the longest time sql

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I need to show the tasks which have taken the longest to complete. So far I have:
(But I’m aware that it isn’t working as when I round the tables my results show both 1 and 2 months when it should be only showing 2, as 2 months is the longest running time

```
SELECT t.task_name,  max(round(months_between  t.start_date,  t.end_date)), e.employee_id, e.task_id
FROM task t, employee e
WHERE t.task_id = e.task_id;
```

Comment: please edit the question and include table definitions and sample data.  thanks.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: It is really weird that `employee` has a `task_id`, instead of `task` having an `employee_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order by difference descending, use `FETCH FIRST` to get the row with max difference. Add `WITH TIES`, to get ties.

```
SELECT t.task_name, t.end_date - t.start_date AS diff, e.employee_id, e.task_id,
FROM task t
INNER JOIN employee e
    ON t.task_id = e.task_id
ORDER BY diff DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the task or tasks (if there be a tie), then we can try using a rank analytic function:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.task_id, t.task_name, SUM(t.end_date - t.start_date) AS days_spent,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(t.end_date - t.start_date) DESC) rnk
    FROM task t
    INNER JOIN employee e
        ON t.task_id = e.task_id
    GROUP BY t.task_id, t.task_name
)

SELECT task_id, task_name, days_spent
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

This answer assumes that the total time spent on a given task is comprised of the time spent by the individual employees associated with that task.  Hence, we need to aggregate by task in the CTE to make it work.